# Build fails when trying to upgrade to latest Gradle (2.2.0)

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the following errors on my Jenkins CI server, when trying to build with the latest Gradle.

It builds in my local environment using the latest Android Studio (2.2 stable), but my Jenkins server fails with this error.

Any ideas for this?  the error means nothing to me...

I did have the Server guy install the JRE8 which I think is required.

```
$ /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/android-native-dev/workspace/gradlew assembleRelease
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not hash input string.
    at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getMd5Hash(PathAssembler.java:63)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.rootDirName(PathAssembler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:45)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:43)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD5 MessageDigest not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:159)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getMd5Hash(PathAssembler.java:58)
    ... 5 more
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
```

I am using the following configuration(s):

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

Project Gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
```

Module Gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html), I have all the config correct, * but I see the docs have the "distributionUrl" still pointing to 2.10-all (think that is just documentation error, and I have it correct here).

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to JRE8 installation instead of JDK8. Consider switching to JDK since gradle assumes JDK installation.

JDK vs JRE [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBNux.png)

As you can see in the image, JRE doesn't include security package which might be responsible for `NoSuchAlgorithmException`.

Answer (score 0):

I think our installation of the JDK was corrupt, or in-correct.  We re-installed the JDK, but used the process described in this page, to insure it was correct.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04